# Best practice for setting up CRON:INDEX from admin

Tags: cron

Magento Cron for all groups are currently set for Each Minute.
Magento Support recommends this too.

However I am facing Server Slowness issues specially in the admin when this is turned on to **each minute**.

Once I changed this to **every 3 hours** the issue got fixed.

Are there any recommendations from the community?

We uplaod around a few hundred SKUs every hour.

Current Version: **Magento Cloud Commerce Pro 2.3.4**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your case you have to separate jobs in different cron groups if they're not already.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

But the slowness you noticed could be caused by frequent cache empty after a reindex. In this case you have to adjust cache refresh policies.

Comment: Is this also the same on the Magento Cloud environment ?
Using community edition on a VPS with SSD works zooming fast.